# Understanding Cormen post office location solution

Tags: algorithm, median

The book "Introduction to algorithms" by Cormen has a question **post office location problem** in chap 9.

> We are given n points p1,p2,...pn with weights w1,w2,....wn. Find a point p(not necessarily one of the input points) that minimizes the sum wi*d(pi,p) where d(a,b) = distance between points a,b.

Looking at the solution to the same , I understand that the ***weighed median*** would be the best solution for this problem.

But I have some fundamental doubts about the actual coding part and the usage.

- If all elements have equal weight , then to find the weighed median, we find the point till which summation of all weights < 1/2. How to extend it here ?
- Given a real scenario having say the number of letters to be delivered at various houses as the weights and we want to minimize the distance to be traveled by finding the location of the post office, x coordinates given ( assuming all houses are in 1 single dimension) , how would we actually go about it ?

Could someone help me in clearing my doubts and understanding the problem.

EDIT :

I was also thinking about a very similar problem : There is a rectangular grid(2d) and different number of people at various places and all want to meet at 1 point (should definitely have integer coordinates) , then what difference would be there from the above problem and how would we solve it ?

Comment: It should be `d(pi, p)`, not `d(pi, pj)`, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still want the point at which the weights sum to 1/2. Pick any point and consider whether you would do better moving one point to the left or one point to the right from there. If you move left one point you reduce the distance to all points on the left by one and increase the distance to all points on the right by one. Whether you win or lose by this depends on the sum of the weights to the left and the sum of the weights to the right. If the weights do not sum to 1/2 you can do better by moving in the direction that has weight > 1/2, so the only point where you can't do better by choosing another one is the point with weight 1/2 - or, to be more accurate, the point where the weights on either side are both <= 1/2.

For 1/2 to be the right answer the weights have to sum to 1, so if you start off with weights which are numbers of letters then you have to divide them by the total number of letters to get them to sum by one. Of course this penalty function doesn't really make sense unless you have to make a separate trip for each letter to be delivered, but I'm assuming that we are supposed to ignore that.

EDIT

For more than one dimension, you pretty much end up solving the problem of minimising the weighted sum of distances directly. Wikipedia describes this in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median. You want to take weights into account, but that doesn't complicate the problem that much. One way of doing it is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares. Unfortunately, that doesn't guarantee that the solution it finds will be on a grid point, or that the nearest grid point to a solution will be the best grid point. It probably won't be too bad, but finding the very best grid point in all possible cases might be trickier.

Comment: I assume you mean the point where weights sum to (1/2)*(sum of weights) , right ?

Comment: Yes. I have Version 1 of the book, and in what seems to be corresponding problem, 10-2, it says at the start that weights are positive numbers summing to one. So if the weights do not sum to one, you are going to have to normalise them by dividing everything by the sum.

Comment: Ok , could you also comment on the further EDIT to my question ?

Comment: OK - answer edited - restricting the answer to grid points might be a problem, though. It feels like it shouldn't be too bad, because the problem is convex, but it might be, unless there's a clever trick somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, if you have seen the solution for the simple weighed median exercise could you please also explain why not simply find the point to which weights sum to 1/2 rather than first finding the median and then trying to get the point for which sum of weights is 1/2 ?

Comment: I don't have the answer book - I was referring to the standard textbook, not the answer book. For the one dimensional problem I don't see any point either in doing anything other than finding the point at which the sum of weights is 1/2 directly, for instance by a linear scan. Looking at the question again I see that it has its own definition of the 2-dimensional problem, with a Manhattan distance. AFAIK you can solve that easily as two separate 1-dimensional problems, one for each co-ordinate - that is, if you care about this particular problem and not something actually useful.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT : this answer is wrong, see comments

What you're looking for is called [center of mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass) (TMHO the weighted median is the center of mass in one dimension).

I didn't get you first question can you detail.

For your example, we would compute the average position weighted by the number of letter per office linked with this position. This would give us : x_center = sum(x_i * w_i) / sum(w_i) and y_center = sum(y_i * w_i) / sum(w_i).

Did it correctly answer your problem ?

Comment: NO it doesnt.   Consider the scenario : House A at x = 1 , letters = 99 , House B at x = 1000 , letters = 1 (considering no of letters as weight) , we get by using center of mass , x_center = 1*99 + 1000*1/100 = 10.99 , resulting in total more distance to be traveled rather than if post office is located at x=1 in which case total distance to be traveled = 999.

Comment: Interesting point, ... I'm thinking about it but have no direct answer to make.

Comment: Center of mass `g` minimises `sum(w_i d(p_i, g)^2)`

Comment: No center of mass is defined as I mentioned, what you defined is an optimal distance point, this should be a property of center of mass, not the definition.

Comment: The min-squared-distance characterization is in fact more general, and serves as a definition when you want centers of mass in a non-vector space setting (ie. where you cannot sum points). It moreover has a straightforward physical interpretation: it is the point with respect to which the total inertia of a solid is minimal. Anyway, it is very different to what is asked here (the weighted median).

Comment: Yes it's different but according to the proprieties @shg seems to look for, your approach might be what he is looking.